# HTML/PHP/CSS/jQuery: Is it possible to depend a:hover on the text or the URL of the link?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I thought about if it would be possible to determine which  link is hovered. Like if I hover http://google.com/ a div should pop up (display:block) and show the google logo and if I hover stackoverflow.com the stackoverflow logo and so on...

Can this be achieved with a:hover or do I have to put every link in to it's own div?

Thanks, really much!

Comment: $(this) is available within the hover event. But you knew that from reading the tutorials.

Comment: Can you provide a mockup of what you're looking for?  It may be possible to do this on the `:before` or `:after` psuedo elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by assigning a listener to all `a` elements.

```
$('a').hover(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  if (href == 'http://stackoverflow.com') {
    // do your thing
  }
});
```

If you don't want to do exact url matching, you can add special data attributes to your a elements and check them instead.

```
<a data-rel = 'stackover' href="http://stackoverflow.com">SO</a>

$('a').hover(function() {
   var rel = $(this).data('rel');
   if (rel == 'stackover') {
     // do your thing
   }
});
```